JSPDF Get Page Information for How much Content is Filled in Current Page
Hi I am having dynamic html content to print this on jspdf I am using its HTML Function so it wont break on the next page
await pdf.html(tempContainer, {
      callback: async(pdf) => {
      },
      margin: [10, 10, 10, 10], // top, left, bottom, right margins
      autoPaging: 'text', // Automatically add new pages if content overflows
      x: 0,
      y: 50,
      // width: 100,
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.5 // Adjusts the resolution of the output
      }
    });

Problem is I need to add footer image in the end but I dont know how much last page is filled, for now I am adding another page in end adding image any one have suggestion how can I place footer at the end
await html2canvas(footerEle).then(async canvas => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const imgWidth = 190; // A4 page width in mm
      const pageHeight = 295; // A4 page height in mm
      const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let margin = 230
      await pdf.addPage();
      await pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, margin, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    });

I have tried using converting whole html content with footer but in case of multiple page line will break and there no way to give spacing above

@KJ for I have dynamic html content in column-count two where I can not depend on  character count, for img2pdf I need as it convert html content with image, which apperently is not visible in jspdf.html() process

For now I have found one way is which is not accurate but close to answer I am getting html element scrollheight then multiplying canvas scale and then dividing with a4 page size - margin getting the approx value how much content is filled

Hi I have finally resolved the issue  I just to get the template scroll height 410 and a4 page height is 291 mm now we are adding margin top and bottom let deduct 20 reming 271 and  after scaling 0.5 * 410 become 200 that much space my content will occupy
